# Generics: Restrict to Interface with pointer receiver

Tags: go, generics

I want to restrict a generic struct to structs that implement certain methods.
For my understanding, this should also work for pointer receivers. The following snippet shows the current problem: *Loadable* does not implement a pointer receiver.

```
type A struct{}
type B struct{}

func (a *A) GetID() {}
func (b *B) GetID() {}

type Loadable interface {
    A | B
    GetID()
}

type Generic[V Loadable] struct {
    Info string
}

func (g *Generic[V]) SomeThing() {
    var y V
    x := &y
    x.GetID() // x.GetID undefined (type *V is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
}
```

How would you solve it?